# How to film this particular aspect in the film Freddy vs Jason of setting someone on fire?

Tags: film-techniques, effects, friday-the-13th, freddy-vs-jason

I rewatched **Freddy vs Jason** and I am a bit on the curious side of things once again.

In the following viedo about Jason's attack on the party out bush, the obese man just sets Jason on fire, which in fact spreads out in the crops:

What I want to know is what sort of fire do they use, if they even use fire? If it is just CGI I would like to know. But how they film someone set on fire and not affected by it is what I am curious about.

Especially after the guy set Jason on fire with a torch and Jason just walked after him and killed him.

**What effects and film techniques are used in order to maintain this particular aspect of the movie?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a guy in a (thick) fire-resistant suit to me! It may seem as though he's on fire for a very long time in the film, but there are actually several separate shots, probably shot hours apart. The actor (most likely a stunt person) may not have been on fire for more than 10 seconds at a time -- just long enough to film one shot. Then, the safety crew off-camera could run in and extinguish the flames with fire extinguishers.

Fire-resistant suits are used all the time in movies requiring effects like this. It's even easier to use one with the Jason Voorhees character, since he wears a mask. That means his whole head could be covered with fire-resistant material. When an actor's face is visible, the flames have to be kept away from the exposed skin (or they can just be added with CGI and practical lighting effects). There are flame- and heat-resistant gels that you can smear on exposed skin, but it's not nearly as effective as a thick flame-resistant suit.